# Warning: There is no outbound connector to deliver mail for this domain

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-365

I was following [this guide](https://medium.com/@j0rt3g4/catch-all-account-on-o365-172622907271) to set up a catchall account.  One of the steps instructs you to set all domains as "internal relay".  When I do that, I get the following warning:

> There is no outbound connector to deliver mail for this domain. Make sure that there's an Outbound Connector of the type OnPremises that matches every 'internal relay' accepted domain. The connector can either have the AllAcceptedDomains flag enabled or have a recipient domain that matches the accepted domain.

The guide does not mention this at all.  If I continue following the guide, will my email still function?  If not, how do I add an outbound connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to perform the steps in the above guide:

1. Create a shared mailbox which is used to receive emails from all domains on O365 tenant
   [image]
2. Create a dynamic distribution group which includes all recipients in the organization
   [image]
3. Configure all domains on O365 tenant to "internal relay"[image]
4. Create a transport rule to redirect emails which are not sent to the recipients in these domains[image]

After I sent emails to three different recipients(**ivan@A.onmicrosoft.com**, **ivan@B.mail.onmicrosoft.com** and **ivan@C.xyz**) without the outbound connector, the emails(Except the email from *ivan@A.onmicrosoft.com* which is a member of the dynamic distribution group) were still sent to the shared mailbox:
[image]
[image]

Based on my test, I think that you don't need to create a connector for internal relay.